# How to make div behave like img in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce

I've written a plugin which inserts photos/video from a popup lightbox into TinyMCE. This worked fine and formatted very well when aligned/wrapped. When it is inserted in HTML like below:

```html
<img src="blah.png" />
```

But since then I added a feature to allow captioning, which uses a wrapper div such as:

```html
<div class="ImageWrapper" width="x" height="x">
  <img src="blah.png" />
  Caption here
</div>
```

There are now a couple of problems I can't fix.

**First:** How do I allow TinyMCE to format/align the div as it did with img?

**Secondly:** How do I prevent the user from selecting any of the contents of the div? Instead clicking should highlight the whole div so formatting and deleting works much more smoothly.

Comment: Look at the CSS for the `img` tag and just add the `div.ImageWrapper` into that same code.

Comment: Sorry, im not sure I understand what you mean. I have no explicit CSS for styling the img tag. The difference in formatting comes from either the browser or TinyMCE itself. Can i make a div tag have the same styling behaviour as an img tag?

Comment: Look at the CSS code applied onto the `img` tag with Chrome's Inspector or Firebug. You should be told a line number and such. Just copy all of that applicable CSS and apply it to your `div`.

Comment: I copied alot of the implicit styling over but it seems not to have helped much. I set it to 
    display: -moz-inline-block;
    display: inline-block;
Which seems to work slightly better. But aligning and deleting the div in TinyMCE is very tempramental. Often backspacing brings content that was below the div into it, and applys the caption style. Id like to just treat this div as an uneditable block, is there a way i can do that? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is using a `<div>` as a wrapper, which is apparently not naturally supported by TinyMCE. You have to go further than fidgeting with some css. TinyMCE being a popular editor, people have already tried and come up with a proper solution. Here's someone who's written a plugin: http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=20319
And there's lots of more info to be found if you google for 'tinymce div plugin': http://www.google.com/#q=tinymce+div+plugin

I don't know what would work best in your situation, so I guess you have to try some of the solutions (plpugins) offered.